# pytest timeout fail test on Windows

Tags: python, multithreading, testing, timeout, pytest

In pytest i can specify timeout for tests using pytest-timeout but it terminates test run instead of failing tests.
There existing solution using signal but it works fo Unix systems only.
Is it possible to fail function after timeout without using SIGALRM.
It's simple to run a using *conftest.py*, for example add

```
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_protocol(item, nextitem):

    if item.config.option.timeout is not None:
        t = Timer(item.config.option.timeout)
    try:
        t.start()
        yield
    finally:
        t.stop
```

But how can i fail test using timer in another thread?
I thought trying send pytest.fail from this thread to main thread but it seems impossible.
Raising exception also affects this new thread but not one with test.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: take a look at this plugin --> https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-timeout/

Comment: it fails test on fox Unix systems using SIGALRM. The problem in making it's analogy for winfows

Comment: have you tried that plug-in?

Comment: Yes. But it's terminates process instead of failing test. From documentation: _For each test item the pytest-timeout plugin starts a timer thread which will terminate the whole process after the specified timeout_. There also signal method that fails tests but it works for Unix systems only.